# Building a full-size lamp using LEGO bricks

Tags: building

On an episode of the TV show ['Home by Novogratz'](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robert_and_Cortney_Novogratz#Home_by_Novogratz) they featured a real, working lamp that was made out of LEGO bricks. More specifically, the creator surrounded an existing lamp with the bricks, glueing them as he went.

Does anyone know if there are any plans for such items available - lamps, or other furniture items?

And are there any sites etc. out there that could provide guidance?

Any help appreciated. I've used LEGO since I was knee-high, but this is a new project for me.

Comment: Do you refer to the lamp including a light emitter (LEGO light brick) or just the stand? For furniture you may better ask another question.

Comment: These guys will do it for you... http://www.etsy.com/shop/MRBrickDesigner

Comment: I would be careful not to use a bulb that gets very hot. I accidentally warped some of my bricks doing that.

Comment: You can find affordable lego built lamps here: http://brickablocks.com/shop/16-lamps Those kenney Lamps are way expensive! These are much more affordable, and are also custom crafted in the USA.

Answer (score 14):

The lamp is made by LEGO artist [Sean Kenney](http://www.seankenney.com/about/). Along with some other items, he sells the lamps on [his website](http://www.seankenney.com/shop/lamps/). They are available in a range of styles and colours, but they are quite expensive.

Since he is selling the lamps I think it is unlikely the plans are available, although the pictures on his website are quite high resolution so you may be able to replicate the design. (I have no idea about the legality of such though).

[image: Lego lamp]

Comment: Seems when the lamp falls down of your desk, you can't "repair" it manually but need to send it to the customer service ;-)

Answer (score -2):

[Here](http://www.instructables.com/id/Lego-Lamp-1/) you go. These are the things needed to build a Lego lamp. How to build it? Well......use your imagination......

Comment: I really, really would not recommend building something which involves cutting LEGO as the first step...